# How can a web page play mp3 on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, mobile-safari

As far as O know, web pages play mp3 sounds by embedding invisible Flash players. Since Flash is not available on mobile webkit (iphone/ipad), how is it possible to play mp3 on this platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 supports these 2 tags ([audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) / [video](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp)) which Safari supports:

In your case, you can use the audio tag.

```
<audio src="horse.ogg" controls="controls">
  your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio
</audio>
```

The only catch is getting the right format for your media. :-)

Safari supports MP3 for audio, and MPEG 4 for video... Firefox supports OGG for audio/video, (I believe Opera does too), and chrome supports both.

Answer (score 0):

More information about the supported file formats in HTML5 are here:
http://www.html5laboratory.com/playing-with-audio-files.php

That links to a really useful page allowing you to test the format support on your particular browser:
http://www.jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/